# No internet even when connected to the WiFi or 4G (iPhone)

Tags: wifi, ios, iphone, cellular-data

I have been having an Internet-related problem on my iPhone 5S for a while now.

It started out with seemingly random Internet disconnection even when there is a perfectly good cellular (4G) or WiFi signal shown on my device. For instance, no emails or messages (like Whatsapp or iMessage) are being pushed to my device, or when I try to search something on the mobile browser, it shows that there is no Internet.

One thing I noticed is that when I do a search on a mobile browser, it seems to load for a long time (more than 10 seconds), only to return a 'No Internet' message.

The only resolve to this matter is to restart my device. I would get connected to Internet with no problems whatsoever (until I encounter the problem again).

I tried doing a reset of network settings, and also a reset of the entire settings. I even went on to do a restore as new (without restoring from a backup). This did not eradicate the problem.

I have already had several appointments at the Apple Genius Bar because of this problem. They didn't seem to know the cause of the problem, nor to resolve it; I got the device exchanged in the end. However the new device I obtained started having this problem as well.

Maybe this is another bug that iOS 8 has? I never had this problem before updating to iOS 8.

Thank you for reading and I hope that somebody has an answer to my problem.

Comment: I had similar problems.. and I don't have a solution but for me it is enough to go into flight mode, wait 5seconds and back when this occurs (I don't have to reboot my phone).. maybe this helps..

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Stephan. Actually I do that first before resorting to a reboot. I have my device in an airplane mode for a period of time and back, but this did not make the problem go away. I still had to do a reboot every time this happens.

Answer (score 2):

The 1st thing to do when you are facing a network misbehaviour is to deal with one way of connection at a time.
This is what the genius at the bar should have told you first.

Practically focus on your **mobile Internet conectivity** first:

- turn off Bluetooth;
- turn off Wi-Fi.

Test your **mobile Internet connectivity** in different places.

Then conclude: your problem is on the **mobile network** side or not.

**If** your mobile phone network is OK

**then** analyse your Wi-Fi in the same way:

- turn off Bluetooth;
- turn off mobile phone network (`Mobile Data`).

Test your **Wi-Fi connectivity** in different places.

Then conclude: your problem is on the **Wi-Fi network** side or not.

Answer (score -2):

Hey just delete vpn and hopefully all will work :) its not a bug its a vpn issues

Comment: No there is no evidence the OQ is related to VPN.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue with WIFI and 3G/4G caused by some VPN deadlock. I played around with the VPN swich in the settings and it worked again.

Comment: There is no evidence the OQ is related to VPN.